# NestJS: This operation is not supported by Mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to get all the elements from database but stucking with this error that says:

```
This operation is not supported by Mongodb driver.
```

I am using MongoDB along with Mongoose to interact with database.

Here is my code where the error happening:

```
import { GetTasksFilterDto } from './dto/get-tasks-filter.dto';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status.enum';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';
import { TaskEntity } from './task.entity';
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';

@EntityRepository(TaskEntity)
export class TaskRepository extends Repository<TaskEntity> {
  async getTasks(filterDto: GetTasksFilterDto): Promise<TaskEntity[]> {
    const { status, search } = filterDto;
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('task');

    // The error happen in this line
    const tasks = await query.getMany();
    return tasks;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the operation?

Comment: I think its the getMany() am I right ?

Comment: It seems you are using `TypeORM` but you include the tag `mongoose`. If mongoose is not relevant, please set the tag as `typeorm` instead

Answer (score 0):

Will this [TypeORM MongoDB Documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/mongodb.md) did the job for me.

The issue was that, the way I am doing it is wrong, **mongodb** doesn't support that way of queries, instead I must use the proper way to do it which by using **MongoRepository** that allows us to create a manager for any Entity.

The code below shows how I solved the problem:

```
async getTasks(filterDto: GetTasksFilterDto): Promise<TaskEntity[]> {
  const { status, search } = filterDto;

  const manager = getMongoRepository(TaskEntity);

  const tasks = await manager.find({
    status: status,
    where: {
      $or: [
        { text: Like(`%${search.toString()}%`) },
        { title: Like(`%${search.toString()}%`) },
      ],
    },
  });

  return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue? This doesn't seem to be a proper answer. If you have solved it please describe what you did to solve it.